# Eigenvalues and BIBO stability

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, satisfiability

Could someone please explain to me the relationship between eigenvalues of a system matrix A and BIBO stability?

I've studied control engineering, and for example in modern control, we say that a system is BIBO satble if the real parts of eigenvalues (of matrix A) are all negative.

But today I had a lecture on digital signal processing, and the professor said that the system would have BIBO stability if all the eigenvalues are smaller than 1. Why is that? How does the condition change for discrete-time systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In control engineering, the system matrix A is given in Laplace transformation and indeed, the real parts of the eigenvalues of matrix A must be all negative  for BIBO-stability.

In digital signal processing, the system matrix A is given in z-Transformation and there, indeed, the absolute values of the eigenvalues of matrix A must be less than 1 for BIBO-stability.

You compared two different system descriptions, hence the confusion.

Comment: I still cannot figure out the relation between Laplace transformation and Z-transformation. I am guessing it has something to do with the fact that in Z-transform all poles should be inside the unit circle in order to have BIBO stability? Is that right?

Comment: Yes. There is a fundamental theorem saying that the eigenvalues of the system matrix are identical to the poles of the transfer function. But the transfer function of course differs, according to the used transformation (Laplace  / z).

Answer (score 0):

For *continuous* systems, the real part of the eigenvalues must be less than one for strict stability.
For *discrete* systems, the eigenvalues must lie inside the unit circle, that is, their modulus must be less than one.